# Merge Two Image on to one Image programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

Hello I am developing the application which requires to merge two Image , My image size are 320*240 by merging both Image I want the size to be 320 * 480 . How can i do this programitically . Following are the Images

[image: First Image]  [image: Second Image]

===================================================================================

[image]

Comment: you want to merge them or place them over one another ?

Comment: Are you starting with two `UIImage`s?

Comment: I want to place them over one another . As i displayed two image I dont want to overlap the image , I want to cover 488 height

Comment: see my answer for Swift 3 implementation

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just tested this, create your context based on the sizes of the images you are working with and draw them on top of each other (this assumes they are the same width):

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width, image1.size.height + image2.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, image1.size.height)];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,image1.size.height,size.width, image2.size.height)];

UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Add image to view
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, finalImage.size.width, finalImage.size.height)];
imageView.image = finalImage;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Oddly, this seems to dramatically degrade quality for me. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: See my answer below about image quality

Answer (score 15):

To avoid degrading image quality, use [UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContext).

> If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale
>   factor of the device’s main screen.

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width, image1.size.height + image2.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0) // Use this call

[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, image1.size.height)];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,image1.size.height,size.width, image2.size.height)];

UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Add image to view
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, finalImage.size.width, finalImage.size.height)];
imageView.image = finalImage;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift Version**

```
func getMixedImg(image1: UIImage, image2: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    var size = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width, image1.size.height + image2.size.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    image1.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, image1.size.height))
    image2.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,image1.size.height,size.width, image2.size.height))
    var finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return finalImage
}
```

**You will get your image to call this function like this :**

```
var myimage1 = UIImage(named: "image1.png")
var myimage2 = UIImage(named: "image2.png")

var finalMixedImage = getMixedImg(myimage1!, image2: myimage2!)
```

Comment: nice elegant code - i implemented it in Swift 3 - see below - and made a func that gets an array instead of 1,2 images....

Answer (score 3):

This implementation works for variadic arguments, so you can pass an unlimited number of images to merge vertically:

```
public static func mergeVertically(images: UIImage...) -> UIImage? {
    let maxWidth = images.reduce(0.0) { max($0, $1.size.width) }
    let totalHeight = images.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.size.height }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: totalHeight), false, 0.0)
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    let _ = images.reduce(CGFloat(0.0)) {
        $1.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: $0), size: $1.size))
        return $0 + $1.size.height
    }

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use two different image-views one below other.and assign two different images.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

accepts an images array and returns an image of the images one on top of the other
takes max sizes into consideration so it's losless

```
func combineTopToBottom(imagesArray:[UIImage]) -> UIImage? {
    var dimensions = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    for image in imagesArray {
        dimensions.width = max(dimensions.width, image!.size.width)
        dimensions.height += max(dimensions.height, image!.size.height)
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(dimensions)

    var lastY = CGFloat(0.0)
    for image in imagesArray {
        image?.draw(in:CGRect(x: 0, y: lastY, width: dimensions.width, height: image!.size.height))
        lastY += image!.size.height
    }

    let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return finalImage
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//ADDED Swift 3.2 and 4.0

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgCamera1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgCamera2: UIImageView!

    let image1 = imgCamera1.image
    let image2 = imgCamera2.image

    let size = CGSize(width: image1?.size.width ?? 0.0, height: (image1?.size.height)! + (image2?.size.height)!)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    image1?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: image1?.size.height ?? 0.0))
    image2?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: image1?.size.height ?? 0.0, width: size.width, height: image2?.size.height ?? 0.0))

    let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    //Add image to view
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: finalImage?.size.width ?? 0.0, height: finalImage?.size.height ?? 0.0))
    imageView.image = finalImage

    //Displaying Image
   // view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIImage *Image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
 UIImage *Image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
 // Set up width height with values.
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

        [Image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

        [Image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(newSize.width,newSize.height,newSize.width,newSize.height*2) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

        UIImage *mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must get contexts of ypur images and then marge it.

```
UIImage *eyes = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eyes"];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(m, n));
    CGContextRef context1 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

    UIImage *mouth = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mouth"];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(m, n));
    CGContextRef context2 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Merge by drawing context with different bounds

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark - merging two images
-(void)mergeimage :(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage{



    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);


    [firstImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y,size.width/2,size.height)];


    [secondImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+(size.width/2),self.view.frame.origin.y,size.width/2,size.height)];

    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about your solution?

Comment: two image merge vertically ,any width height images you can merge.