# Different frames for images Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add frames on images just like editing application in which we can add more than one image in single UIimageview and save that image to gallery. I have searched lot about it, does anyone know how to do that or any reference for this?

Comment: can you explain in detail ?

Comment: What have you tried? We are not going to code for you from scratch.Also be more detailed while posting a Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to add multiple images to single UIImageView. You can create single image from multiple images and then set to UIImageView, This could be solution.

Here is link, How To combine multiple images into single one.
[merge-multiple-images-into-one-image-in-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878008/merge-multiple-images-into-one-image-in-iphone)

This is Objective C code you need to port to swift.

Comment: I kind of have a similar question . Is it possible to add multiple UIImageViews into a single frame ? :) I mean I want to break an image down into multiple pieces and put them all in different ImageViews but same frame so once they're all there together they present the main image

Comment: Yes it is Possible, Add UIView and Use UIImageview as You need in UIView.@DanialKosarifa