# Merging multiple image into single image

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage

I want to merge multiple images into single image while saving to camera roll.
Actually,I'm having different images in different views.I'm having 3 images in one view and also 4 images when selecting layout with 4 frames.someone help me how to merge them.

my sharing code:

```
 CGRect rect=[self.previewView bounds];
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0.0f);
 CGSize size=CGSizeMake(self.previewView.frame.size.width, self.previewView.frame.size.height);
 if(selectButtonTag==2)
 {
 [self.doubleFrameViewcapturedImg1.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];
 [self.doubleFrameViewcapturedImg2.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];
  }
 CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 [self.previewView.layer renderInContext:context];
 UIImage *newImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 NSArray *activity=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                   UIActivityTypeMail,
                   UIActivityTypeMessage,
                   UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                   UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                   UIActivityTypeAirDrop
                   , nil];
 UIActivityViewController *ShareView=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[newImage,activity] applicationActivities:nil];
 ShareView.popoverPresentationController.sourceView=self.view;
 [self presentViewController:ShareView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878008/merge-multiple-images-into-one-image-in-iphone) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273271/merge-two-image-on-to-one-image-programmatically-in-iphone) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273271/merge-two-image-on-to-one-image-programmatically-in-iphone   ....this is what my app looks like but there will be 3 and also even 4 images

Comment: so you could do same as that post with your app

Comment: i don't need to overlap them just the middle border should not be appeared and it should look like single image.

Comment: i'll try and i'll say

Comment: My issue was not solved @HuyNghia..see while sharing the image the 2 images or 3 images whatever the images are there,they should be viewed like single image(merged as single image).did u get me...

Comment: please check that code ..by using tag value I'm getting views .if I select button tag =3 means,there will be 3 images ..

Comment: did you check newImage exactly merge two image try display it

Comment: one more thing  [self.doubleFrameViewcapturedImg1.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];
 [self.doubleFrameViewcapturedImg2.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.5];
frame in these lines not true. image 2 will be draw overlap image1

Comment: yes.it will display as a single one but here in between both or 3 images there will be separated lines ,those lines should not be displayed and all images should be shared as a single image.

Comment: I think this is not the correct way to show multiple images as single one...

Comment: show your expect image look like ? I can't get you.

Comment: please check that image .it is having 2 separate images but converted to single image ..it should exactly look like this

Comment: plz see discussion chat

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using `CoreGraphics`,for more details just follow the tutorial by CodeTutePlus [AdvancedImageTechnicsCoreGraphics](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-advanced-uiimage-techniques--mobile-17207)

Comment: Actually,I'm having different layouts of picking images like collage i need merge the images .did u get me like collage my view will be .if  I select layout with 4 views those 4 images should be merged