# UINavigationBar title view alignment issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have set an `ImageView` as title view for a specific ViewController whereas the other controllers have `UILabel` as titleView. I used the following code to set title view,

```
UIImageView *imageTitle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:imageTitle];
```

I have tried using this one as well,

```
UIImageView *imageTitle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo"]];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:imageTitle];
```

**The issue is, when I pop back to the view controller the title view 
stays on left for few seconds. I'm not sure what's the reason for this? Please let me know where I'm going wrong???**!
[image]

P.S: The issue occurs in iOS 7 only!

Here is the sample project with this issue - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97646145/Issue/NavigationTitleView.zip

**Update**

As @FahimParkar suggested, I used a 320x44 image for the titleview. The delay in positioning seems little as the image is wide. ***Is this the only solution for this issue?***

Link to download trial project with 320x44 image -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97646145/Issue/NavigationTitleView_Updated.zip

Comment: Can you check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199980/how-to-put-an-image-in-the-center-of-navigationbar-of-a-uiviewcontroller or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361500/set-navigation-bar-image-in-ios-7

Comment: @DhavalBhadania No.. One is about navigation bar... the other is about how to set title view.. I already set title view, but it is having problem when popped back!

Comment: it is for few second?? and after that it is all right?

Comment: `[self.navigationItem setTitleView:imageTitle];` this is correct implementation

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi Yes.. It happens only for few secs.. then its fine

Comment: what is the size of image? make sure you have 320x44 & 640x88

Comment: @Fahim I need 320*44 & 640*88 for a title view? Isn't that for navigationbar? Am I wrong?

Comment: @Nina : try to use 320x44 and I think you will not have this issue...

Comment: @FahimParkar Will try and let you know!

Comment: @FahimParkar Its still happening... but as the image is wide enough to occupy the complete space the visibility is less.. I tried this with a sample image.. Is this the solution??

Comment: @Nina : I downloaded your project.. let me check

Comment: @Nina : can you upload sample project without POD? I dont have POD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choise for setting navigation properly.

**First:**

setting Titleview as you did like bellow:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UIView *navView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
    UIImageView *imgviw=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    imgviw.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    imgviw.center=navView.center; // this is display your image at center of navigation bar.
    imgviw.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"passowrd.png"];
    [navView addSubview:imgviw];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = navView;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

That Output like:-

[image]

**Second:**

Setting navigation image as par your requirement for particulare `view-controller`. create image for navigation with same size of navigation bar. And set using Bellow code.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a issue in `autoresizing`

```
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LOGO.png"]];
imgView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
imgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.navigationItem.titleView = imgView;
```

Comment: Where you are adding the image in titleView? In `viewDidLoad` or `viewWiilAppear`?

Comment: I have a separate class that stacks all main view controller, i do this part in that class..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `ViewWillAppear` method hope this helps you:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Logo"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];

self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your navigationbar title view inside `viewDidLoad` and not `viewWillAppear`.